# What are the typical annotation styles for optical flow?

Tags: computer-vision, optical-flow

I am coming from a background in deep learning techniques for computer vision like image classification, action recognition from skeletal data, and semantic segmentation. I have read several papers on Optical Flow, but I'm wondering what the nature of the annotation is for optical flow.

Specifically, supposing we have two images `I_1`, and `I_2`, both of the same resolution. For a dense optical flow prediction task, there must be some ground truth image `G` of the same resolution with annotations at each pixel.

My question is, what are the values of `G`?

For instance, suppose a pixel in image `I_1` at `(x_1, y_1)` "moves" to pixel `(x_2, y_2)` in `I_2`, I can imagine the ground truth being a tuple of values `(g_x, g_y)`. These could be the normalized `l_1` distances computed coordinate-wise but I'm not sure if this is what's done in practice, or is it a single regression value per pixel?

I'm assuming pixels that have no movement are given a value of 0. There may even be some "don't train/don't train" pixels, perhaps given a sentinel value of -1.

Any insights on how the labeling of optical flow works much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See for examples the Middlebury datasets: https://vision.middlebury.edu/flow/data/